# Update query for 110 million records won't finish

Tags: mysql

We are using MySQL.
We have a very long table (110m * 7) and we regularly add in new records to this table (when doing that, we upload csv files so never a really painful process even large # of records).

Now we need to add a new column to this table to distinguish the records in some way. To be specific, the most recent added about 10 million records will be flagged as type 2 and all the old records will be flagged as type 1. And in the future, we will be putting in new records for both types.

At first, we tried the approach 1 as below, but it ran for more than 24 hours without complaining anything and the host server has always been responsive.

```
-- ====================================================
-- start of approach 1
-- ====================================================

-- Add column.
ALTER TABLE 
  bond_price 
ADD 
  bp_name_version SMALLINT 
;


-- Set value 1 for BOND_CHARACTER types.
UPDATE 
  bond_price 
SET 
  bp_name_version = 1 
WHERE 
  bp_serial_id < 107480325 
;


-- Set value 2 for BOND_CHARACTER_EIKON types.
UPDATE 
  bond_price 
SET 
  bp_name_version = 2 
WHERE 
  bp_serial_id >= 107480325 
;


-- Set a NOT NULL constrain on the new column
ALTER TABLE 
  bond_price 
ALTER 
  bp_name_version SET NOT NULL 
;


-- ====================================================
-- END of approach 1
-- ====================================================
```

We lost our faith after 24 hours, thinking setting a conditional clause might has made it difficult for such a long table. So we tried approach 2 which is doing approach 1 step by step and without conditional clause.

So we firstly execute the following query and it finished within seconds.

```
-- Add column.
ALTER TABLE 
  bond_price 
ADD 
  bp_name_version SMALLINT 
;
```

We then execute the following query to put value 1 to all records, hoping later on we can change the value for only 10 million records to 2.

```
-- Set value 1 for all records.
UPDATE 
  bond_price 
SET 
  bp_name_version = 1;
```

But this query has run for over 24 hours till now, again without complaining for anything.

We have been monitoring the server by:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

And the 'Set value 1' query is still active and the server is still very responsive.

OUR QUESTIONS:

1. Is this speed what one should expect, considering the record number is over 100 million?
2. Is there a possibility that this query will not work but just get stuck forever? Is there anyway to tell?
3. Is there anyway to improve the speed? Or do it a different way?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which of your 4 queries is it that takes long? Do you have an index on `bp_serial_id`?

Comment: What is the structure of your table, which indexes does it have, etc? it looks to me that either bp_serial_id is not an index or you don't have enough memory and index is actually stored on disk and is, therefore, slow. You might also try partitioning your table on bp_serial_id: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-key.html

Comment: Well we couldn't know which of the 4 queries for sure, but from the second try it seems the second query is taking ages.

Comment: Hi Ashalynd, yes I was going to ask whether it could be becoz of the index. We do have 3 index columns for this table but not including the bp_serial_id.

Comment: What version of MySQL server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the basis of the data, but 110+ million records in one push is probably a bit nuts.

Why not trying to find some other criteria, do a loop, and do them in smaller chunks... maybe based on some "Add" Date, or some other field in the structure.  Or, just use the bp_serial_id, such as (again, handled by a loop)

**pseudo-code to update 1 million max at a time**

```
maxSerialForType1 = 107480325 

for cycle = 0 to 110
   startSerialID = cycle * 1000000
   endSerialID = (cycle +1 ) * 1000000

   if startSerialID < maxSerialForType1
      UPDATE bond_price 
         SET bp_name_version = 1
         WHERE bp_serial_id < maxSerialForType1
           AND bp_serial_id >= startSerialID
           AND bp_serial_id < endSerialID
   end for update type 1

   if startSerialID > maxSerialForType1
      UPDATE bond_price 
         SET bp_name_version = 2
         WHERE bp_serial_id > maxSerialForType1
           AND bp_serial_id >= startSerialID
           AND bp_serial_id < endSerialID
   end for update type 2
end of loop
```

So this, if made like a stored procedure will update the 110 million for you.

I would then make a suggestion, that when importing new records into a temp table with the bp_name_version value assigned there, THEN pull them into the final table so you don't have to go through trying to update 110+ million each time.

Comment: this is exactly the answer.  In my experience, updates take the longest and should be batched - or avoided whenever possible.  Alternatively, create a one-to-one table and do an INSERT of ID plus new flag.

Comment: @user3384166, for grins and not choking on it, you could even try it with the cycle count from 0-3 and having the number of records updated to only 10 vs 1 million, just to get your syntax working... THEN change to the million multiplier.  And definitely make sure you have an index on the bp_serial_id.

Comment: Thanks guys! Here is the update of our trials: the loop approach might not be an option since we tried 10K and 5k record updating and they took 5 minutes and 2.5 minutes. Although this was while we were vacuuming the database so it could have affected the speed...still too slow.

Comment: It seems more than one ppl has suggested creating a new one-to-one table and then put them together. Can anyone advice specifically how to do it? We have tried to use [Insert temp_table select *,1 from ...where...] to create a new table which is identical to the old one but has the extra column we need. But the problem is that the bp_serial_id is the system-generated serial id, we will lose this property in the new table but we need that.